# Static member variables are not translated by gettext

Tags: c++, gettext

## Problem

My software is translated via gettext. The locales are called at the very beginning of the main function. Unfortunately, the static member variables of my monostate "Messages" which contains all message strings are not translated as static member variables are processed before the main. The rest of the software (the static functions of the "Messages" class) is translated as expected.

I mean I could use functions instead but I would prefer a solution where the variables remain variables.

## Question

How can I get the static member variables translated without making them functions?

## Example

Messages.h

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

#define _(STRING) boost::locale::translate(STRING)

class Messages
{
    const std::string example_var = _("This message is not translated.");

    void example_func(int i) noexcept
    {
        return boost::str(boost::format(_("Just use %1% somehow.")) % i);
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include "Messages.h"

int main()
{
    boost::locale::generator gen;

    //Specify the location of dictionaries.
    gen.add_messages_path("./translations/");
    gen.add_messages_domain("de_DE");

    //Generate the locales and imbue them to the iostream.
    std::locale::global(gen(""));
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale());
    std::cerr.imbue(std::locale());

    //Not translated
    std::cout << Messages::example_var << std::endl;

    //Translated
    std::cout << Messages::example_func() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to illustrate.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Ok. Give me a second.

Comment: Initialize then later :) They can be static still. Just don’t initialize them where you do right now. Or you can also initialize the locale before those variables are initialized: add a dummy variable before and initialize it by evaluating a lambda. The body of lambda can initialize gettext and locale.

Comment: If all your static variables are in same TU, you might move locale's initialization into static variable before the other global. but playing with static order initialization can easily go to a *fiasco*.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Please don't post answers in comments.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Uh-huh, so then the similarly pedantic types will complain that the answer is too short. Nope. It's not good enough for an answer, and you know it. Hopefully.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica I tested your hint and it works! Just put a dummy variable like an int before all static member variable initializations and assign a lambda function to it which is immediately called and calls the locales and returns and int so that the dummy variable is satisfied. You saved me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Who judges an answer by the number of characters it has?

Comment: Not me. You’d have to ask those that do. And anyway, what I wrote is just a comment. An answer would need a bit more meat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it with the comment of Reinstate Monica.
Just put an unused variable before all static member variables and calculate its value in a lambda function. The value itself does not matter at all. The only thing that matter is that the lambda function makes the right locale function calls.
See my solution below:

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

#define _(STRING) boost::locale::translate(STRING)

class Messages
{
    //Member variables
private:
    int init_locales = []() -> int
            {
        //Localization
        if(!Settings::get_lang().empty())
        {
            boost::locale::generator gen;

            //Specify the location of dictionaries.
            gen.add_messages_path("./translations/");
            gen.add_messages_domain(Settings::get_lang());

            //Generate the locales and imbue them to the iostream.
            std::locale::global(gen(""));
            std::cout.imbue(std::locale());
            std::cerr.imbue(std::locale());
        }

        return 0;
            }();
public:
    const std::string example_var = _("This message is translated now!");

    //Member functions
    void example_func(int i) noexcept
    {
        return boost::str(boost::format(_("Just use %1% somehow.")) % i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep in mind that the macro `_()` serves a double purpose: It translates stings at runtime and it marks strings as translatable when you invoke the `gettext` program inside of your build system for string translation.

For cases like this, the idiomatic way is to define another macro `N_()`:

```
#define N_(STRING) STRING
```

Think of it as no-op gettext.

Then make sure that these strings are recognized and extracted by `xgettext` in your build system by invoking `xgettext` with the option `--keyword=N_`. In standard Makefiles this should be the case by default.

And at runtime, just invoke your translation function on the variables:

```
std::cout << boost::locale::translate(Messages::example_var) << std::endl;
```

In a nutshell: Do not change the runtime behavior of your program just to make sure that your variable is initialized with the translated string constant for your selected locale. That is not necessary. Instead, just mark the string constant as translatable and translate it at runtime, when you use it.